# Are IN queries executed in parallel on app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Suppose that we have a query like this:

```
query.filter("field IN",['value1','value2'...,'valueN'])
```

I know that this translates to N different queries(N <= 30) but don't know if they are executed in parallel or not ? What is the correct answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are executed in parallel, if you run the appstats you should see all request run.